# Insert command works on command line but not in pymongo Error: key '$date' must not start with '$'

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to populate a table with data automatically using pymongo where I have been manually inserting before. The issue I am having is that my insert statement is working in the command line but throwing a "key '$date' must not start with '$'" error in pymongo. Note: I have recieved this same error when trying to use update() in the mongo command line.

Im using python3 and mongodb 4.0.10

Here is my code:

**Command line query:**

```
device_query = {
    "_id":device_ids[i],
    "customer_id":"18012320",
    "rep":"MVO2",
    "active":"true",
    "description":descriptions[i],
    "location":"test, test" ,
    "system":"MM 60 gallon, 40 LPM, pre-HPR",
    "device_type":"O2",
    "iot_start_date":{
        "$date":{
            "$numberLong":"1563598800000"
        }
    },
    "iot_expire_date":{
        "$date":{
            "$numberLong":expirations[i]
        }
    }
}
device.insert_one(device_query)`
```

This code inserts the document successfully

**pymongo code:**

```
device_query = {
    "_id":device_ids[i],
    "customer_id":"18012320",
    "rep":"MVO2",
    "active":"true",
    "description":descriptions[i],
    "location":"test, test" ,
    "system":"MM 60 gallon, 40 LPM, pre-HPR",
    "device_type":"O2",
    "iot_start_date":{
        "$date":{
            "$numberLong":"1563598800000"
        }
    },
    "iot_expire_date":{
        "$date":{
            "$numberLong":expirations[i]
        }
    }
}
device.insert_one(device_query)`
```

This code throws
key '$date' must not start with '$'

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use `$date` and `$numberLong` in pymongo code, just simply pass the value in the field.

Try this :

```
device_query = {
    "_id":device_ids[i],
    "customer_id":"18012320",
    "rep":"MVO2",
    "active":"true",
    "description":descriptions[i],
    "location":"test, test" ,
    "system":"MM 60 gallon, 40 LPM, pre-HPR",
    "device_type":"O2",
    "iot_start_date":1563598800000,
    "iot_expire_date":expirations[i]
}
device.insert_one(device_query)
```